# Switch To Multiple Merchant Account With Activemerchant Gem For Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant, paypal

I am writing a Rails application and I understand that gateway objects are created with Activemerchant via the merchant's information. Usually, we would initialise the object via:

```
# development.rb
config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    paypal_options = {
      login: someone@mail.com,
      password: password123456here,
      signature: awesomeSignatureHere
    }
    ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
```

Now I have two merchants on my application and I would want to have payments being credited to their paypal accounts directly without going through me. What would be the recommended steps in the event the user choose to pay Vendor A via the form at the view level, the constant of EXPRESS_GATEWAY would be switched to the appropriate merchant provided I have the merchants' information for their API stored in the database?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by creating a method in the necessary model and creating instance variable for it.

Comment: Could you check which user did receive the payment? 

Because having multiple accounts. Without save this extra information I think it's not accesible.

Comment: @joseglego thanks for responding! I believe at that point of time, the payment routing was through user prior to the merchants. Anyway, it has been solved :) thanks again!